# Linearlayout with weightSum and three layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

Below is the item of layout i am using in listview.The issue is that when i make visibility of countlayout gone in some items of list I expect vibelayout to be exactly at same place where countlayout was since weigtSum is 3.But it is appearing slightly right of  position where countlayout was.

I am using View.GONE so that countlayout space is assigned to vibelayout but its not happening.. vibelayout is appearing slightly right of position where countlayout was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `android:layout_width="0dp"` in all 3 layouts. It will solve your problem

Comment: i know that..but my requirement is is that vibelayout shoud appear in place of countlayout when countlayout is not required..check the layout..

Comment: I am using View.GONE so that countlayout space is assigned to vibelayout but its not happening.. vibelayout is appearing slightly right of position where countlayout was.

Comment: `0dp` will occupy same space for  all layouts, if you will use `wrap_content` it will take width as per content in layout.